# Sorting data stored on ID's with List.js

Tags: javascript, html, html-table, innerhtml, list.js

## The Problem

List.js isn't properly sorting numbers on my HTML-Table. This is happening because I'm using inner-HTML on the place of numbers, sort works fine if I just put the numbers and not an ID.

> **Why not just put the numbers on the table like you said?**

I admit that's the best solution, it gains on performance and don't use any javascript, **BUT :**

- I need to modify the data a couple of times a day.
- I intend to use and display the data in other places as well, and not just the table.
- And in consequence, a pain to modify the data on all my HTML pages, where I could modify just the .js and them, all HTML would be updated.

---

### What I want:

Make the button "Numbers" properly sort data inside of each:

```
document.getElementById("mushroom_N").innerHTML = "some_number";
```

and not the actual ID name. (in this case, each "mushroom_N")

---

### Conditions:

- A solution that uses [List.js](http://listjs.com/), and not a different plugin.
- I'm not using jQuery, the ideal solution would be one that also don't use it.

---

My code is [HERE](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YvqbLj?editors=0110) on codepen if you prefer.

Thanks for your attention!

```js
var options = {
  valueNames: ['name', 'number']
};

var userList = new List('users', options);

function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("demo0").innerHTML = 10;
  document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = 1000;
  document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = 1;
  document.getElementById("demo3").innerHTML = 100;
}
```

```css
.list {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

td {
  padding: 10px;
  border: solid 1px #eee;
}

input {
  border: solid 1px #ccc;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 7px 14px;
  margin-bottom: 10px
}

input:focus {
  outline: none;
  border-color: #aaa;
}

.sort {
  padding: 8px 30px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  border: none;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #f44336;
  height: 30px;
}

.sort:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #b71c1c;
}

.sort:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.sort:after {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 5px solid transparent;
  border-right: 5px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 5px solid transparent;
  content: "";
  position: relative;
  top: -10px;
  right: -5px;
}

.sort.asc:after {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 5px solid transparent;
  border-right: 5px solid transparent;
  border-top: 5px solid #fff;
  content: "";
  position: relative;
  top: 4px;
  right: -5px;
}

.sort.desc:after {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 5px solid transparent;
  border-right: 5px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 5px solid #fff;
  content: "";
  position: relative;
  top: -4px;
  right: -5px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
</head>

<body onload="myFunction()">

  <div id="users">

    <!-- "Search" -->
    <input class="search" placeholder="Search" />

    <!-- "Sort Buttons" -->
    <button class="sort" data-sort="name">A -> Z</button>
    <button class="sort" data-sort="number">Numbers</button>

    <!-- "The List" -->
    <ul class="list">
      <li>
        <h3 class="name">Mario</h3>
        <span class="number"><p id="demo3"></p></span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <h3 class="name">Luigi</h3>
        <span class="number"><p id="demo1"></p></span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <h3 class="name">Peach</h3>
        <span class="number"><p id="demo2"></p></span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <h3 class="name">Toad</h3>
        <span class="number"><p id="demo0"></p></span>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <!-- "List.js" -->
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/list.js/1.5.0/list.min.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welp, I did it!

You just need to create an array and put the elements inside of another one. The [Codepen](https://codepen.io/Mokai_Momiji/pen/LrZwGK?editors=1010) for someone interested or having the same problem of mine.

```js
var mushs = [
  "100", // Mario
  "10", // Luigi
  "1000", // Peach
  "1" // Toad

  // A change in the values will affect all places at the same time.

];

var options = {
  valueNames: ['name', 'mushrooms'],
  item: '<tr><td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric name"></td><td class="mushrooms"></td></tr>'
};

var values = [{
    name: 'Mario',
    mushrooms: mushs[0]
  },
  {
    name: 'Luigi',
    mushrooms: mushs[1]
  },
  {
    name: 'Peach',
    mushrooms: mushs[2]
  },
  {
    name: 'Toad',
    mushrooms: mushs[3]
  }
];

var userList = new List('users', options, values);

document.getElementById("mushroom_0").innerHTML = mushs[0];
document.getElementById("mushroom_1").innerHTML = mushs[1];
document.getElementById("mushroom_2").innerHTML = mushs[2];
document.getElementById("mushroom_3").innerHTML = mushs[3];
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 20px;
}

input {
  border: solid 1px #ccc;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 7px 14px;
  margin-bottom: 10px
}

input:focus {
  outline: none;
  border-color: #aaa;
}
```

```html
<div id="users">

  <input class="search" placeholder="Search">

  <table class="mdl-data-table mdl-js-data-table">
    <div id="mdl-table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">
            <button class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--icon sort" data-sort="name">
              <i class="mdl-color-text--red-500 material-icons">sort_by_alpha</i>
            </button>
          </th>
          <th>
            <button class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--icon sort" data-sort="mushrooms">
              <i class="mdl-color-text--red-500 material-icons">swap_vertical_circle</i>
            </button>
          </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>

      <tbody class="list"></tbody>

    </div>
  </table>
</div>

<p></p>

<div>Hey, I know that Mario got <span id="mushroom_0"></span> mushrooms, also, Luigi got <span id="mushroom_1"></span> of them, Peach was greed and got at least <span id="mushroom_2"></span> mushs, and Toad got only <span id="mushroom_3"></span>, himself.</div>



<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/material-design-lite@1.3.0/material.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/material-design-lite@1.3.0/dist/material.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/javve/list.js@1.5.0/dist/list.min.js"></script>
```